# Windows App determine if TextBlock is trimmed

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, windows

I have an GridItem that has a fixed Height/Width.

It contains a textblock that has the max line set.

How can I determine if this text is trimmed? 
I want to add special functionality if it is trimmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up making a static function

```
    // Ensure block does not have MAXLINES or text trimming set prior to checking
    public static bool IsTruncated(TextBlock block, int maxLines)
    {
        if (block == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("block");
        }

        //the cut-off height is the height at which text will be cut off in the UI
        var cutOffHeight = maxLines * block.LineHeight;

        //determine whether the actual height of the TextBlock is greater than the cut-off height
        return block.ActualHeight > cutOffHeight;
    }
```

The trick is to make sure that Maxlines and text trimming is NOT set on the Textblock prior to running this function. After this function returns, that is when the Maxlines is set. In my case I just saved the returned Boolean in a containing object so I knew it was longer. Then I set maxlines and another button to see the extended content based on that Boolean.

Comment: Care to explain why my solution doesn't work? IMHO, mine is better.

Comment: I didn't say yours didn't work. I just posted the solution that we actually went with. Besides the fact our solution is shorter, we are avoiding data binding which was the main issue. I appreciate your answer and we upvoted it several times.

Answer (score 6):

**Old Way - when TextWrapping is set to None**

To know if a `TextBlock` is trimmed, we can subscribe to its `SizeChanged` event and compare its `ActualWidth` to the `MaxWidth` you specified. To get the **right** `ActualWidth` of the `TextBlock`, we will need to leave the `TextTrimming` to its default value (i.e. `TextTrimming.None`), and set it to trimmed once the width goes over.

**New Way - when TextWrapping is set to Wrap**

Now that I know because the `TextWrapping` is set to `Wrap` and assume the `VirticalAlignment` is not specified (default to `Stretch`), the `Width` will always stay the same. We only need to monitor the `SizeChanged` event when the actual height of the `TextBlock` exceeds the height of its parent.

Let's use a `Behavior` to encapsulate all the logic above. What needs to be mentioned here is that a `static` helper class with a bunch of attached properties or a new control that inherits from `TextBlock` can do exactly the same thing; but being a big Blend fan, I prefer to use `Behaviors` whenever possible.

**The Behavior**

```cs
public class TextBlockAutoTrimBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public bool IsTrimmed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTrimmedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsTrimmedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTrimmedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsTrimmed", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBlockAutoTrimBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; set; }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        this.AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)this.AssociatedObject;

        // subscribe to the SizeChanged event so we will know when the Width of the TextBlock goes over the MaxWidth
        textBlock.SizeChanged += TextBlock_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void TextBlock_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ignore the first time height change
        if (e.PreviousSize.Height != 0)
        {
            var textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;

            // notify the IsTrimmed dp so your viewmodel property will be notified via data binding
            this.IsTrimmed = true;
            // unsubscribe the event as we don't need it anymore
            textBlock.SizeChanged -= TextBlock_SizeChanged;

            // then we trim the TextBlock
            textBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
        }
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        var textBlock = (TextBlock)this.AssociatedObject;
        textBlock.SizeChanged += TextBlock_SizeChanged;
    }
}
```

**The XAML**

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="73" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Background="#FFD2A6A6" Margin="628,329,538,366">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="test" FontSize="29.333">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:TextBlockAutoTrimBehavior IsTrimmed="{Binding IsTrimmedInVm}" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Note that the `Behavior` exposes a dependency property `IsTrimmed`, you can data bind it to a property in your viewmodel (i.e. `IsTrimmedInVm` in this case).

*P.S. There's no `FormattedText` function in WinRT otherwise the implementation could be a little bit different.*

Comment: Does the width take into account height also? Meaning if my box of width 100 is 2 lines high, is the width of that text now 200?

Comment: Oh, if this is the case, it's even simpler. Actually we don't need the `MaxWidth` anymore. Because the `TextBlock` is stretched horizontally and vertically, its width will stay the same. The height will change only when it exceeds its parent height. So all we need to do is listen to the `SizeChanged` event and do stuff when the height goes over. I've updated the `behavior` and also added `TextWrapping` to the xaml. It now should work on any number of lines.